# TFS Check-In Consistently Excludes Files in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have an enormous project tree hosted in a customer TFS 2015 server. I have a local instance of TFS 2015 so that I can test some build and release workflows in an isolated environment. When I copy the 10GB of contents from the customer TFS project to a local TFS project, and then check it in, certain files are being consistently excluded (I have cleared and re-added the files several times). I don't know the extent of what's being omitted. I just know that there are some assemblies (as well as the directories where they are hosted) that have been colocated into the tree but which end-up not being committed every time. It's obviously very confusing to figure out what exactly is missing since they exist in my local filesystem but the build and my TFS web UI reports these as missing.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: what are the extensions of the files? is there a pattern to what is being excluded or is it random fie types? What are the path lengths of the files being excluded?

Comment: @JamesReed For the files that I'm specifically noticing, the whole directory is missing. The files themselves are assemblies (".dll"). That's a great question about the path length; I hadn't thought of that. However, it's very short, and, at any rate, it's in a shorter root path than the original. As far as include/exclude, the tree is far too large to know for sure. The directory that I'm concerned with has DLLs and PDBs in it.

Comment: By default, TFS will exclude dll's from checkin. I think it will also ignore bin and obj folders as typically binary files should not be checked in to TFS. When you add files / folders to TFS there will be a list of excluded files. I expect your dll's and pdb's are in that list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS excludes .dll files from pending changes by default, but it is possible to customize folders and filetypes to include-exclude. This can be done using .tfignore file, detailed documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#tfignore).

But, if that problem is yours only, consider not checking in the .tfignore file, - as other members of the team might prefer exisiting include/exclude pattern.